# .htaccess ONLY for directory not for the files in them

Tags: .htaccess, file-permissions

I have a .htaccess file:

```
<limit GET>
order deny,allow  
deny from all  
allow from 123.456.789
</limit>
ErrorDocument 403 /403.shtml
```

However, this affects the entire directory and the files in them. I just want this to affect the main directory URL, but not the files in it.

For example:

`http://test.com/test/` = 403 Forbidden Error

`http://test.com/test/file.png` = No Error

`http://test.com/test/file2.png` = No Error

How can I alter my .htaccess file to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you just want to prohibit directory listings.  
`Options -Indexes` will do that.

Comment: Hmm, I added it, but it doesn't seem to work. I might be placing it in the wrong position, could you show me an example? P.S. this .htaccess file is in the directory I want this .htaccess file to affect. In my example's case, this .htaccess file is in `http://test.com/text`.